# swift: when I open the view controller and press the gesture recognizer for the first time it says that i pressed it twice. how to fix this?

Tags: ios, swift, double, uigesturerecognizer, ibaction

When I open my view controller I have 4 gesture recognizers, when I tap twice this shout happen:

```
@IBOutlet var doubleTap: UITapGestureRecognizer!
@IBAction func doubleTapAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    doubleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
    print("Button was 2x")
}
```

but when I press one of the 4 buttons for the first time(I pressed only one time.) it prints that I tapped twice. after the first time it works fine.

Can someone tell my how to fix this?

thanks for reading my question I hope someone can help me.

if you don't understand my question please comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the first time the gesture recognizer is set to recognize one single tap. You change that to be two taps, but you set it in the wrong place, because you already tapped once, so it enters the action and executed the code there:

```
self.doubleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2 // This is wrong here!
print("Button was 2x")
```

So it changes the recognizer to recognize two taps, but it already recognized one (that's why that code gets executed) so it prints that text as well.

It makes no sense that you set that every time you tap, you just need to do it once. A good place to do this is `viewDidLoad`.

You could also set the number of the required taps in the interface builder.

code example:

```
@IBOutlet var doubleTap: UITapGestureRecognizer!
@IBAction func doubleTapAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    print("doubleTap was 2x")
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.doubleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
}
```

Comment: can you explain more plz. if I can't do a ibaction in the viewdidload and i have 4 gesture recognizers.

Comment: What do you mean? I already gave you the answer to your problem.

Comment: i did what you said i added self. and I tried to put it in the viewdidload but it is not working? so maybe I did something rong...

Comment: when I added it to the viewdidload i removed it in the ibaction. but i needed to put it in the viewdidload and the ibaction. so tnx for your help :)

Comment: I marked it as the right answer and added a example code but that is still in review